# How to get $resource key to pass to a view in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-service, nstore

I need to get the resource key from an array of resources in my AngularJS SPA.
I use a resource like this:

```
var answers = $resource('/api/answers/:id', {id: '@id'})
```

It connects to my node.js backend which loads JSON from nstore. The "API" is simply getting data out of a [nStore](https://github.com/creationix/nstore) db, I just do a `res.end(result)` sending my result like this:

```
{
  "1moabd0c": {
    "q1": "asdf",
    "q2": "3",
    "q3": [
      "false",
      "true"
    ],
    "q4": "a@a.com"
  },
  "2loe5p5p": {
    "q1": "edsds",
    "q2": "3",
    "q3": [
      "false",
      "true"
    ],
    "q4": "sdfwe@mai.com"
  }
}
```

When I do give a parameter (like, calling "/api/answers/1moabd0c" from that first object), I get only that one result, like this:

```
{
  "1moabd0c": {
    "q1": "asdf",
    "q2": "3",
    "q3": [
      "false",
      "true"
    ],
    "q4": "a@a.com"
  }
}
```

So how do I extract that object key?

I use the resources in a view:

```
tbody
      tr(ng-repeat='answer in answers')
        td {{answer.q4}}
        td
          a(href='#/answers/{{answer.key}}') Open
```

But it does not work. I tried using {{asnwer.key}}, {{answer.id}} there...what else can I use to get that hash?

Edit: when I do this in my controller:

```
  $scope.answers = Answers.query()
  window.x = $scope.answers;
```

And then in the window I log out x, I get an array, but that array has `$$hashKey` props. My guess those are angulars' own hash keys. I need the original ones. The array looks like this (edited it a bit to fit here nicely)

```
[
    {
        "$$hashKey": "005",
        "q1": "asdf",
        "q2": "3",
        "q3": [
            "false",
            "true"
        ],
        "q4": "a@a.com",
        __proto__: g /* Which seems to be the angular resource object literal, with $delete, $get and stuff */,
    },
    {
        "$$hashKey": "009",
        "q1": "Ovojejedanodgovor",
        "q2": "4",
        "q3": [
            "false",
            "true"
        ],
        "q4": "babaa@a.com",
        __proto__: g /* again this obj */
    }
]
```

Comment: if you want to remove the "prefix", use `$http`

Comment: @user1737909 You mean in my service definition? Instead of $resource, I should write down my own get, post, put, del actions on that service? I was trying to avoid that :(

Comment: I'm afraid $resource doesn't allow to "unwrap"

Comment: Hmm. Ok, thanks. I'll have to get verbose there.
Btw, if you put it in as an answer, I can accept it.